# Emacs C-x C-c overriding save-buffers-kill-terminal if within last open frame

Tags: eclipse, emacs, daemon

I have setup **emacs -daemon** to run on login to Gnome and associated **emacsclient** with .cpp and .py files that I work with in Eclipse in order that emacs is used as my default editor for these files when selected within Eclipse. This way I can get a good work flow combining the editing capabilities of emacs and the  project/build management and debugging facilities of Eclipse.

Anyhoo... I want to prevent C-x C-c from closing the Emacs frame I am currently editing in if it is the only Emacs frame remaining visible at any given moment.

**Is there a way of querying the daemon Emacs process in order to find out how many frames are open and override the default C-x C-c behaviour to do nothing (if only 1 frame remaining) thereby ensuring there is always at least one visible frame open at all times?**

Some elisp that implements this behaviour and that can be added to my .emacs would be great.

**Bonus Points :¬)** 
I have aliases that map vi, emacs etc... to "emacsclient -c", so I get emacs frames coming and going all the time in general. A further enhancement would be for Eclipse to send files that I want to edit directly to a *specific* frame e.g. the 1st frame opened with emacsclient -c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within emacs-clients, `save-buffers-kill-terminal` only calls `server-save-buffers-kill-terminal`, so you might want to install an advice onto that to not affect non-client frames. The `frame-list` function cal be used to introspect the currently existing frames. It apparently always includes one entry for the daemon process itself, and then one for each open frame.

```
(defadvice server-save-buffers-kill-terminal (around dont-kill-last-client-frame activate)
  (when (< 2 (length (frame-list)))
    ad-do-it))
```

Answer (score 1):

Make emacs immortal (what ever the way you've started it) :

```
(defadvice kill-emacs (around emacs-immortal) nil)
(ad-activate 'kill-emacs)
```

Use `ad-deactivate` to deactivate this trick.