# Emacs: "C-x #" killing buffer

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs-helm

I've been searching for an answer to this issue, I found

[Emacs Client: difference between C-x k and C-x #](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317065/emacs-client-difference-between-c-x-k-and-c-x)
and
[Emacs C-x C-c overriding save-buffers-kill-terminal if within last open frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691028/emacs-c-x-c-c-overriding-save-buffers-kill-terminal-if-within-last-open-frame)

but it not exactly related. Here's the issue:

I have emacs started as a daemon and use emacsclient to connect to it.
I primary use emacsclient inside the OS X terminal with the -nw option.

The specfic command i use is:
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient /tmp/foo -nw -c -s /tmp/emacs501/work_guigo

So I have two files in /tmp/, named foo and baa.
In my terminal.app, I open foo with 
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient /tmp/foo -nw -c -s /tmp/emacs501/work_guigo

Emacs tells me, "When done with a buffer, type C-x #", so I do that.
I'm done with it for now, but I'm not done with it for today, so I want the foo file to remain in my "C-x b" buffers list.

So I'm back in the terminal, I open baa with
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient /tmp/baa -nw -c -s /tmp/emacs501/work_guigo

Now when I do a C-x b, I don't see foo in the list of open buffers.

This sucks. What should I do?

---some additional info:
emacs 24.5
using helm for "C-x b"

Comment: "When done with a buffer, type C-x #" - it sounds like you aren't done with the buffer if you want to visit it again later.  Are you just trying to close the emacsclient window?

Comment: true, but same probkem with c x 5 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, I find the answer to my own question.

In this case, it was a matter of having

```
(setq server-kill-new-buffers nil)
```

near the top of the init.el